# How to convert row to column in notepad++

Tags: formatting, row, notepad++

How can I convert

```
 testext
```

to

```
t
e
s
t
e
x
t
```

Please note there is no delimiter. Is there any way?

Comment: This is more of row to a column, no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to Search → Find → Replace (Ctrl+F) and type following:

> Find: `(.)`
>   Replace: `$1\n`
>   SearchMode: `Regular Expression`
>   Direction: `Down`

Then place the caret at the beginning of the text and hit "Replace All".

Comment: Technically this is correct but it is not really useful. For example, how would I use this technique for adding a number to the end of my div id tags and what happens once my list of div ID's goes over 10-11 numbers?

Comment: @TylerLazenby Either you change the regex formula to your needs or you write a little program using a html parser.

Comment: No "Direction" in Notepad++ 7.5.6, just make sure Wrap Around is not selected.

Answer (score 0):

**NotePad++ transpose cols to rows**

- Ctrl+H
- Find: (,)
- Replace: (,\n) or (\n)
- SearchMode: Regular Expression
- Click on Replace All

**NotePad++ transpose rows to cols**

- Ctrl+H
- Find: (\n)
- Replace: (,)  or  ( )
- SearchMode: Regular Expression
- Click on Replace All

Comment: Where have you seen a comma in the text? Why do you put parenthesis in the replacement part?