# How to convert row to two column in notepad++ (Replace every second 'space' to 'new row')

Tags: formatting, notepad++

How can I convert

> -8995505.412022 -7384606.618716 -3879261.615165 1317611.003282 -7354544.798239 -2501563.005552 -7354544.798239 -2501563.005552 -7354544.798239 -2501563.005552 -7368905.012551 -2506243.328407

to

```
-8995505.412022 -7384606.618716 
-3879261.615165 1317611.003282 
-7354544.798239 -2501563.005552 
-7354544.798239 -2501563.005552 
-7354544.798239 -2501563.005552 
-7368905.012551 -2506243.328407
```

in notepad++ (or another)?
Replace every second 'space' to 'new row'

Comment: [How to convert row to column in notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29259799/how-to-convert-row-to-column-in-notepad)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert row to column in notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29259799/how-to-convert-row-to-column-in-notepad)

Comment: That's not really a duplicate. The other question is how to break after each character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to go:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\S+\s+\S+)\s+`
- Replace with: `$1\n`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Where:

`\S` stands for any NON white space